# What do I have to change to make this code functional?

Tags: i2c, lcd

I have a joystick, an I2C 16x2 character display, and an Arduino. I want to move the joystick and get an on-screen character (specifically, the letter h) to move in the direction that I pushed the joystick. Here is the Arduino code.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
int xVal; 
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
int yVal; 

int blockPos[]= {8, 0};
int blockPosBack[]= {8, 0};

int ycal;
int xcal;
void setup() {

    lcd.begin();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.backlight();
Serial.begin(9600); 

pinMode(A0, INPUT); 

pinMode(A2, INPUT);
lcd.setCursor(blockPos[0], blockPos[1]);
//lcd.print("h");


ycal = 500;
xcal = 514;
}

void loop() {

xVal = analogRead(A0); 

yVal = analogRead(A2); 

Serial.print(" Y is...");

Serial.print(yVal); 

Serial.print(" X is...");

Serial.println(xVal);

blockPosBack[0] = blockPos[0];
blockPosBack[1] = blockPos[1];

if(xVal < (xcal - 150)){
  if(blockPos[0] > 0){
    blockPos[0] - 1;
    }
  }

  if(xVal > (xcal + 150)){
  if(blockPos[0] < 15){
    blockPos[0] + 1;
    }
  }

  if(yVal < (ycal - 150)){
  if(blockPos[1] > 0){
    blockPos[1] -1;
    }
  }

  if(yVal > (ycal + 150)){
  if(blockPos[1] < 1){
    blockPos[0] +1;
    }
  }
if(((blockPosBack[0]) != (blockPos[0])) && ((blockPosBack[1]) != (blockPos[1])){
  lcd.clear();}
  lcd.setCursor(blockPos[0], blockPos[1]);
  lcd.print("h");
}
```

The problem is, I get a message saying that "expected ')' before '!' token". How do I solve this, and how do I change the code to make it functional?

Edit: I learnt that '!' is not the same as 'not equal to', which is '!='. I tried this, but now the h just sits at the initial position but doesn't move when I move the joystick. What do I have to change in the code to make it work?

Comment: `if(blockPos[1] < 1){blockPos[0] +1;}` - shouldn't that be `blockPos[1] +1` ?

Comment: Please describe with your own words what you want to achieve with the line `if(((blockPosBack[0]) ! (blockPos[0])) && ((blockPosBack[1]) ! (blockPos[1])){`

Comment: @MrGerber Without it, the Arduino keeps clearing the display, which results in the flickering of the character displayed on screen.

Comment: That is ugly code. If there is any possibility at all for misinterpretation you should write stuff out using multiple lines. And comment everything.

Comment: Let me rephrase- Describe with normal language what conditions you want to catch with this if-statement.

Comment: @MrGerber the 'lcd.clear()'

Comment: @DirkBruere I'm the kind of guy who gets code for one part of the project off the internet (in this instance the code for the joystick), and then frankensteins my own additions onto it. (Then asks on the internet why my code isn't working). I don't really prepare it for other people, because I can understand it fine myself. Writing neater code is one of my goals for coding.

Comment: I see that you run the lcd.clear()-function, but under what conditions do you want to run that?

Comment: @MrGerber What do you mean by conditions? If I don't clear the LCD when the position on the 'h' changes, instead of the one h moving around on its own, it will leave behind a trail of 'h'.

Comment: `condition - kənˈdɪʃ(ə)n - [noun]
3. a situation that must exist before something else is possible or permitted.
"for a member to borrow money, three conditions have to be met"`

Comment: @MrGerber Oh, sorry. So I have the blockPosBack (stands for "block position backup") array which becomes the same as the blockPos array at the start of the loop. Then it runs through all the if statements which check if the joystick has been moved at all. After all that, the large if statement at the bottom check to see whether the blockPosBack array is the same as the blockPos array, if it's the same, it means that I have not moved the joystick. And, there is no reason to clear the screen, because the 'h' does not need to be moved.

Comment: Yes, then I follow you :) Then what you want is `!=` to check if unequal, but you dont want &&, you want ||, so you clear if the column coordinate OR the row coordinate has changed

Comment: @MrGerber Ahhh thanks for that!, Yes it makes sense that way... But the 'h' still doesn't move at all though, it's still stuck in that initial position...

Comment: @Bruce Abbott Yes, it should, I changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in my comment, to have proper condition for clearing the display, the condition you should want to meet are:

`if ( (newX != previousX) OR (newY != previousY)) {
    clearLCD()
}`

EDIT: Or else, what you're saying is that you're only clearing the display when you have changed both X and Y *at the same time*

And to adress your problem with the 'h' not moving, you need to change the lines 
`blockPos[0] - 1;` etc

into

`blockPos[0] = blockPos[0] -1;`

or

`blockPos[0]--;`

or else, you're not really assigning the new value to the variable containing the position to use in the display.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I added a delay of 100 on the four if statements. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

!! is not a valid logical operator, you probably meant || for locical OR?

Did you verify that the condition to change the blockpos value is actually fulfilled? Means are you sure one of your if blocks is actually executed?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be '!' for NOT. I made the edits. The code still doesn't work.

Comment: @skillz21 ! is a unary operator. I think you want != (not equal to).

Comment: @Jon Yeah I had a look into that, I changed it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you describe in your own words what you want this line of code to do?

Comment: @Humpawumpa I want the 'h' on the display to stop flickering.

Comment: Did you verify that the condition to change the blockpos value is actually fulfilled? Means are you sure one of your if blocks is actually executed?

Comment: How do I do that? I did 'Serial.print(blockPos[0]);' but no, the values of both blockPos values don't change... why?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should have edited the code way better, if you want help and want us to understand you must edit it properly.

```
if(((blockPosBack[0]) != (blockPos[0])) && ((blockPosBack[1]) != (blockPos[1])){
  lcd.clear();}
  lcd.setCursor(blockPos[0], blockPos[1]);
  lcd.print("h");
}
```

I took some time to understand that lcd.setCursor and lcd.print wansn't part of the if. When you are using 2 different sensors or components, you must try them separatly first, and when you got them both working fine that's when you use them together. 
[https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/JoyStick](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/JoyStick)

This is an example pretty much more simple than yours, so i just think you must try lcd first, and when you understand how lcd works, and how joystick works, you can easly interact them.

Comment: If you wondered about how those five last lines worked, it was not harder than asking OP, or in fact - reading the comments section, it was explained there an hour before your answer was posted. Also, referring to another example code is not really answering the question.

Comment: just saying it was a bad edit, it wasnt critical in this code because it was short, but in real big codes this edit is critical. And im refering to another example because it was way simple, you didn't understand my aswer, i "advised" for future codes

Comment: Yeah I did, but you didn't understand my comment. Imo, advise for the future is not an answer to a question, but belongs in a comment, or as an addendum to a proper answer to the OPs question. Remember that these questions should be useful to anyone else reading the Q/A as well.